# Calling custom controller method from view on click and then updating view in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I've been looking into AJAX recently and trying to apply it to my Rails app. **I'm having trouble understanding how to call a custom controller method from the view and then updating the view**.

I've attempted to add a helper_method to a controller where I update the attribute I need. However, I'm not sure how to call this method from the view, and if I do, how I re-render a partial affected by that change. Does replace_html fit in here?

=============

Here's a concrete explanation of what I'm looking for, if my explanation wasn't clear:

Currently, I am defining @question in the GamesController show method, and then doing this in the view:

```
#games/show.html.erb
...
<%= link_to 'Next Question', @question, remote: 'true', :class=> "btn" %>
```

I have the QuestionsController responding to :html and :js. Then, I render what I need to in the following file and update the "`#question-show`" div in `games/show.html.erb`

```
#questions/show.js.erb
$('#question-show').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'question') %>");
```

The `questions/_question.html.erb` partial contains info on that particular question.

This works fine right now. However, I have multiple question per game, and I want the `<%= link_to 'Next Question', @question, remote: 'true', :class=> 
btn" %>` in `games/show.html.erb` to first update what @question is. I have this now in GamesController, but it's not linked to my view:

```
def next_question
    @game.progress += 1
    @question = Question.find(@game.questions[@game.progress])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end
helper_method :next_question
```

After I update what @question is, I want to re-render the  `#question-show` div with the updated question.

===============

Anyways, thanks for your time! First time posting on Stack Overflow, so please let me know if there's something wrong with my submission. I've spent a while looking at similar questions, but haven't had any luck. Thank you!

Comment: not sure to understand it correct. you want to render the `questions/show.js.erb` to update the selected question?

Comment: I want to update what `@question` is, and then render `questions/show.js.erb` for that `@question`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.

you can render your `show.js.erb` from another controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { head :no_content }
  format.js { render 'questions/show' } 
end
```

but i would prefer local variables like `format.js { render 'questions/show', locals:{ question: @question } }`

Comment: Gotcha. So when I run the helper method, it will automatically render 'questions/show' with the local variable question being @question. How do I call the helper method from my view on button click? I found online that I can do it in line with <%= next_question %>, but how do I only call the helper method on a button click? Is there any way to do this with link_to, or must I do this through jQuery?

Comment: it's another question. you can put your custom route to your `routes.rb` and call it via `link_to` method. but i would prefer to use the `show route` and use the helper just to get the new question object.

Comment: Thanks! I got the behavior I wanted by adding a custom `PATCH` route and then calling it via `link_to` with `remote: 'true'`. The `.js.erb` file then renders a partial. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out the answer I was looking for is a combination of everything I've seen so far on SO.

The major thing I forgot to do was to add a route.

```
#config/routes.rb
..
patch 'games/:id/next_question' => 'games#next_question', as: :games_next_question
```

Here is my controller method defining next_question, which is a PATCH method.

```
 #controllers/games_controller.rb
     ..
     before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :next_question]
     ..
     def next_question
        if @game.progress.equal?(@game.questions.length - 1)
          @game.update_attribute(:progress, 0)
        else
          @game.update_attribute(:progress, @game.progress + 1)
        end
        @question = @game.questions[@game.progress]
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js {}
        end
      end
```

Here is the corresponding .js.erb file:

```
#views/games/next_question.js.erb
$('#question-show').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'question') %>");
```

And my view:

```
#views/games/show.html/erb
..
<%= link_to 'Next Question', games_next_question_path(:id => @game.id), method: :patch, remote: 'true', :class => "btn" %>
```

Thank you for your help!